# Draw a 1-pixel wide box around a zoomable UIIMageView that is inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView. The image should be zoomable so I return it in the scrollview's `viewForZoomingInScrollView` method:

`- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return _imageView;
}`

The goal is to draw a 1-pixel-wide box around this image. The box should resize to be around the UIIMageView without scaling the thickness of its lines. Think of it as the guidelines/boxes around an image inside PowerPoint or any image editing program.

I created a `CALayer` called `borderBoxLayer` that contains a `UIBiezerPath` drawn around the image.
I tried the following 4 methods:

1- Adding this layer to the UIImageView won't work because it will scale the box lines too (because they're part of the UIImageView). The box lines should be always 1 pixel wide.

2- I used a CADisplayLink to REDRAW the layer every frame

```
CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateLayers)];
[displayLink setPreferredFramesPerSecond:60];
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

inside `updateLayers`, I get the current frame of the imageView to be able to change the frame of the `borderBoxLayer`. This method works "partially". The location and size of the box work as expected, but there's a lag that makes it "flashy" when zooming in/out. I also tried removing the layer and re-adding it with the updated frame, but it's the same result.

3- I created a fake UIView that sits on top of the ScrollView and I added the `borderBoxLayer` to this `fakeView`, using the same display link. It reduced the lag but it's still there.

4- Also tried to call `updateLayers` in the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods like `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`, `scrollViewDidEndZooming`, etc. And also add my own `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to the scrollview and call `updateLayer` in the handler but was much slower than methods #2 and #3.

The best results I got were from #2 and #3. However, the scrollview zooming is refreshing at a rate higher than my CADisplayLink.
Any idea how I can call `updateLayers` at a higher rate or achieve the result I want?
Thanks.

image caption: on left: original image size. on right: zoomed in but box thickness is the same.

[image: on left: original image size. on right: zoomed in but box thickness is the same]

Comment: Have you tried using `imageView.layer.borderWidth`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `borderWidth` of the `imageView`

```
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
imageView.layer.borderColor = //Whatever color
```

If, as a result, the border zooms in as well, you can just set the `borderWith` to 0.0 in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and set it back to 1.0 in `scrollViewDidEndZooming`